# Call java binary from PHP not possible

Tags: php, exec

Hi I would like to call java using PHP exec() function but it fails (no output of e.g. `exec('/usr/bin/java -version')`.

I am running apache with PHP as Fast-CGI (with fcgid) on debian wheezy.

The java binary is available under /usr/bin/java and is callable from command line, e.g. '/usr/bin/java -version' returns expected information.

Calling this in context of the apache/suexec user works as well from command line (sudo -u www-data /usr/bin/java -version).

But called from PHP usig `exec()` or checked with `is_executable('/usr/bin/java')` does not work.

What am I missing?

Comment: This question is over on StackOverflow, and from 2010, but maybe it will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128619/run-java-class-file-from-php-script-on-a-website

Comment: Thank you for the hint Katie. I already checked some simmilar questions but none of them helped in my case because my problems were rather trivial. See my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my own question here.
It turned out, there are 2 different problems.

1) First is trivial, I forgot about active `open_basedir` setting which did not include `/usr/bin` directory. But anyway even after including it, `/usr/bin/java` stil wasn't executable according to PHPs `is_executable()`. So I had to disable this feature, which is not critical in my case of a local DEV server. Maybe someone has an idea how to make it executable with `open_basedir` set.

2) Second problem ist strange but true :-) The call of "java -version", for some weird reason, does not write to STDOUT but to STDERR, so PHPs `exec()` is not able to deliver the output.